# How could I apply visited pseudo-class for :tel URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a problem with  tag. I have list of clickable phone numbers on the page and I want to mark used urls.

I created small example and tried to use :visited selector to change color for clicked urls, but it doesn't work.

Let me show the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .phone:visited {
            color: red;
        }
        .phone {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <a class="phone" href="tel:#">Call me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I found in Google Chrome inspector, that css works correctly (I manually added "visited" class and url's color was changed), but browser doesn't mark url as visited after click.

Is there any chance to fix this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a note to those answering, the question is *not* tagged with jQuery; and the solutions posted so far - using jQuery for no apparent reason - are entirely possible - and easily so - with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Incidentally, having thought about it, the problem you have may be that the CSS is working as designed, it's just that the `tel` protocol triggers the browser to launch the appropriate application to deal with the link, it doesn't, itself, visit that URI. Workarounds may be the only way to implement this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I think, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen on desktop, because desktop browsers don't know what to do with `tel:`.

You could use something like jQuery to achieve this on desktop.

```
$('.phone').click(function() {
  $('.phone').css({"color": 'red'});
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, url will be blue after page reloading and it's a main problem. If I'm not mistaken, I checked "tel:" url on my iphone and the issue was repeated. I will re-check on real device again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign class through jquery.

```js
 $('.phone').click(function () {   
      $(this).addClass("visited");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .visited {
            color: red !important;
         background-color: yellow;
        }
        .phone {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <a class="phone" href="#">Call me</a>
    <a class="phone" href="#">Calling you</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! It's just a temporary decision, because if I will reload page, url will have blue color again. The main idea is to store history of calls on browser level to allow user not to remember all numbers, that he/she used

Comment: One solution is: when .phone is clicked, add "visited" class, get its content (phone number) and store in cookie or localStorage. When page is loaded, check cookie or localStorage and go through all .phone elements, if one phone number appears in cookie/localStorage, make its corresponding .phone element "visited".

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it's look like workaround more, not the native solution. I hope to find way to use native url behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So manage with javascript session and additional css class will be handle your problem

```
<style type="text/css">
        .selected {
            color: red !important;
        }
        .phone {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    //I assumed there is only one a link so tried with index 0
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("visited") != null) a[0].classList.add("selected"); //check visited link then add class selected
         a[0].addEventListener("click",function(){ 
                    sessionStorage.setItem("visited","true");//set session visited
                    this.classList.add("selected"); 
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare `.phone` first before `.phone:visited` in your css.

Comment: This wont make a difference in this example because `.phone:visited` is more specific (value of 20) than `.phone` (value of 10) so the order doesn't matter and the visited styles will win. [See this easy calculator.](https://specificity.keegan.st/) The problem is browsers don't record visits to `tel` links so they are not marked as visited.